# How can I translate model and attribute names of an Rails Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, internationalization, rails-engines

The usual way to translate model and attribute names of a Rails project are:

```
MyModel.model_name.human

MyModel.human_attribute_name :myattribute
```

or, when you are using a form for MyModel:

```
form.label :myattribute
```

The locale file `config/locales/en.yml` looks like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      mymodel:
        one: TranslatedMyModel
        other: TranslatedMyModels
  attributes:
    mymodel:
      myattribute: translated attribute
```

And this works for a regular Rails project. When the same model would be part of an Engine called `MyEngine`, the same would be put into `config/locales/en.yml` of the Engine and prefixed with my_engine:

```
en:
  my_engine:
      activerecord:
        models:
          mymodel:
            one: TranslatedMyModel
            other: TranslatedMyModels
      attributes:
        mymodel:
          myattribute: translated attribute
```

The my_engine prefix works for various translations, **except** when trying to get model or attribute names via the above mentioned methods.

I have set up a fresh Rails project and Engine with Rails 3.2.11 to test that, but without success.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 8):

I got help on the Rails issues section on github. This is the answer:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      'my_engine/mymodel':
        one: TranslatedMyModel
        other: TranslatedMyModels
    attributes:
      'my_engine/mymodel':
        myattribute: translated attribute
```